# Problem with centralized form validation framework for an ASP.NET(C#) 3.5 web app using ASP.NET validation controls and AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, validation

I need to implement a centralized form validation framework for my ASP.NET(C#) 3.5 website.

And for this I have tried the following solutions-

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattgi/archive/2007/01/23/asp-net-ajax-validators.aspx
2. http://validationframework.codeplex.com/

I have added the .dll file in my project's BIN folder and for Matt Gibb's solution I have also added the tagMapping code to web.config file. But for both of the solution, when I ran the project I noticed it doesn't have any effect on the validation controls.

So none of the above mentioned solution are working for me.

Can anyone figured out what I'm doing wrong?

Or can anyone let me know any other reliable working solution?

Regards,
nzahra

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the #2 option would be the best... are you using .NET's validation controls or the validators within this framework?  We are going to have to see code to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: For solution #2, I have just added ValidationFramework.dll file inside the project's BIN folder. And I'm using the simple .Net validation controls from VS tool box.

Comment: OK.  So, is there an issue still with this solution that you are experiencing?  And what specifically with this framework are you having trouble with?